# Запрос Mysql соединение таблиц и выборка по ним

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть 3 таблички: `Names`, `Specifications` и `Information`. Нужно вывести имя товара, характеристики и их значения, при этом сделать выборку по цене (её я и не смог реализовать). Прошу помощи..

[image: таблица имен товаров]

[image: таблица с контентом]

[image: таблица с характеристиками]

Comment: Сформулируйте покорректнее вопрос. Подпишите где какая таблица, где в них поле с ценой(???), расскажите, что сделали сами и что из этого не получилось

Comment: @carapuz, судя по всему цена - одна из строк в `Specifications`. Зачем автору такие извращения - не понятно, т.е. не ясно, почему свойства хранятся именно в таком виде, почему то, что есть всегда, не внесено в `Names`. Зачем такая перенормализация?

Comment: В задании сказали записать имена характеристик и их значения в разные таблички.

Answer (score 1):

Всетаки написал запрос.

```
SELECT name.product_name,spec.attr_name,inform.content,spec.id_gods
FROM Names name 
JOIN specifications spec on (name.id_gods = spec.id_gods)
JOIN inf inform on(spec.id_key = inform.id_key)
where name.id_gods in (select id_gods 
                       from inf 
                       where id_key in (select id_key 
                       from specifications 
                       where attr_name = 'price') and inf.content >'$price'
);
```